# If I hide a tableView cell it still takes up space. How do I remove it entirely?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, show-hide

I have a `tableView` with two `cells` with code like this:

```
viewModel.content.bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { _, _, item in
    return self.cellFactory(item: item)
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)

func cellFactory(item: Any) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cellViewModel = item as? StaticSupportTableViewCellViewModel {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StaticSupportTableViewCell.identifier) as? StaticSupportTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.viewModel = cellViewModel
        cell.isHidden = true
        return cell
    } else if let cellViewModels = item as? SupportTableViewCellViewModel {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SupportTableViewCell.identifier) as? SupportTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.viewModel = cellViewModels
        return cell
    } else { return UITableViewCell() }
}
```

Now, I would like to hide the first cell and wrote `cell.isHidden = true`. While this does hide the cell, it still takes up invisible space, pushing the other `cell` down. How do I make it completely dissapear? I have tried `cell.removeFromSuperView()` but no luck. I have also tried setting the height with `estimatedHeightForRowAt` delegate and on the cell itself.

Comment: I don't see cell.isHidden = true anywhere.

Comment: I added it afterwards just to test and it didn't work :) This is the standard code.

Comment: declare the cell variable (not let) you want to remove outside the function and the try again to remove it from superview.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions:

**1.** If the dimensions of your cells are dynamic, you can use constraint
to reset the StaticSupportTableViewCell size. I recommend StackView
for this.

---

**2.** If your cell has a static height, You can set 0 in the heightForRowAt func.

> The code example is for RxSwift

### Define height value to all CellViewModels like this:

```
// MARK: - HeightDefinable

extension StaticSupportTableViewCellViewModel: HeightDefinable {

   static func defaultHeight() -> CGFloat {
       return 60
   }
}
```

### Set TableView delegate

```
tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

### Set height

Here, by using the information you get from viewModel.content items, you can make it hide by giving the cell height 0 according to a condition you want. Here is an example.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    guard let element = viewModel.content.value?[indexPath.row] else {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        
        return 0
    }

    return type(of: element).defaultHeight()
}
```

> To be able to use it as viewModel.content.value, the content must be defined as BehaviorRelay.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is like when you are trying to hide a tree in a forest, You can't do it directly and if you wanna totally hide it you need to do it from its roots to be totally disappeared, I think it's the same issue here and all you need to do is to remove the unneeded item from the array or move it to another array and then return its count and reload the tableView

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wat you are trying to implement but if you don't want it at all, try filtering your `viewModel.content` or if you have a condition to hiding a specific item apply it inside `filter` before binding.

for example:

```swift
viewModel.content
.filter{!($0 is StaticSupportTableViewCellViewModel)}
.bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { _, _, item in
    return self.cellFactory(item: item)
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```